# Calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$

Tags: limits

So it is obvious that this limit goes to $0$. I can reason that it does, say some hand-wavy things like "The bottom goes to infinity while top stays at 
$1$ and so the limit is $0$", but there is no rigor in that. If I wanted a rigid proof would I just apply the squeeze theorem? squeeze it between $0$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$? Or is there an easier more straightforward way.

Thanks.

Comment: Squeeze Theorem isn't a terrible idea. Try writing it out! I suspect there may be a difficulty. If you know epsilon-delta proofs, I would use that method. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

> $$\lim\limits_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac 1{x^n}=0$$

Can you finish the rest? I have provided the hidden answer below. Look if you are truly stuck!

> $$\begin{align*}L=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac 1{\sqrt{1+x+x^2}} & =\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac {\tfrac 1x}{\sqrt{\frac 1{x^2}+\frac 1x+1}}\\ & =\frac {0}{\sqrt{0+0+1}}\\ & =0\end{align*}$$

Comment: @Sorfosh No problem! It's just how I first learned limits to infinity for rational functions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac1{\infty}$ is not an indeterminate form thus we can conlcude by [algebraic theorems](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitProofs.aspx), as an alternative by squeeze theorem

$$0 \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{1}{x}\to0$$

and the last can be easily proved by $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

Comment: I am trying to avoid $1/infty$ as it seems to lack rigor. I may be wrong though

Comment: @Sorfosh You can refer to the basic algebraic theorems on limits, take a look here http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LimitProofs.aspx

Comment: @Sorfosh or as an alternative reduce to $1/x$ by inequalities and then prove that by the definition that is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, then for $x>\frac1{\varepsilon}$ we have
$$0<\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}<\frac1{\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac1x<\varepsilon$$